# I jump high or low?

Tags: riddle

> When both are the same, I jump low.
>
> When both are different, I jump high.
>
> You can use me to add, but I don't know maths.
>
> What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is

> Binary XOR Operator(Symbol :- ^)

Solution:

> If we call the inputs A and B and the output C we can show the XOR function as:
>
> ```
>     A         B       C
>     0  XOR    0   ->  0
>     0  XOR    1   ->  1
>     1  XOR    0   ->  1
>     1  XOR    1   ->  0
> ```

Comment: you should hide also the operation block

Comment: Does this satisfy the third line?

Answer (score 2):

> Weighing scales (not the digital ones)

Explanation:

> When both sides have the same weight, the scale's bar remains low.
>  When the 2 sides have different weight, it tilts and one side jumps high.